# Is there a way to control ffplay audio volume from command line and from key commands on Mac OSX?

Tags: ffmpeg, playback

We want to use ffplay to monitor live RTMP feeds. We have a script to open an instance of ffplay for each feed. We would like to control the initial volume of the video to be around 30 out of 100. We would also like to be able to raise or lower the volume via key commands during the stream. We are referring to this doc: http://ffmpeg.org/ffplay.html

We've tried the main option -volume 30, to try and start the volume at 30/100. FFplay says unrecognized option when it sees -volume on the command line.

Also, we've tried using 9 and 0 to lower or raise the volume once the player is up and playing the live RTMP feed. These key commands seem to have no effect on the player's volume.

Are there other shell parameters, and other key commands, that are known to work on all builds/OS's for ffplay? If not, why change these basic functions from release and O/S ato other release? In any case what works on MacOSX? Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

- you can exec 'ffplay --help|grep volume' to see what displayed.
- on my Mac, ffplay version is 4.4.1, I can start like this: ffplay -volume 30 rtmp://xxx.com/live/test
- if you want to control volume when playing, you can use 9,0 to decrease and increase volume.

the following is what ffplay says:

```
 ffplay --help|grep volume
ffplay version 4.4.1 Copyright (c) 2003-2021 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple clang version 12.0.0 (clang-1200.0.32.29)
  configuration: --enable-demuxer=dash --enable-libxml2
  libavutil      56. 70.100 / 56. 70.100
  libavcodec     58.134.100 / 58.134.100
  libavformat    58. 76.100 / 58. 76.100
  libavdevice    58. 13.100 / 58. 13.100
  libavfilter     7.110.100 /  7.110.100
  libswscale      5.  9.100 /  5.  9.100
  libswresample   3.  9.100 /  3.  9.100
-volume volume      set startup volume 0=min 100=max
  dropout_transition <float>      ..F.A...... Transition time, in seconds, for volume renormalization when an input stream ends. (from 0 to INT_MAX) (default 2)
  attacks           <string>     ..F.A...... set time over which increase of volume is determined (default "0")
  decays            <string>     ..F.A...... set time over which decrease of volume is determined (default "0.8")
  volume            <double>     ..F.A...... set initial volume (from -900 to 0) (default 0)
  delay             <double>     ..F.A...... set delay for samples before sending them to volume adjuster (from 0 to 20) (default 0)
volume AVOptions:
  volume            <string>     ..F.A....T. set volume adjustment expression (default "1.0")
     once            0            ..F.A...... eval volume expression once
     frame           1            ..F.A...... eval volume expression per-frame
  sono_v            <string>     ..FV....... set sonogram volume (default "16")
  volume            <string>     ..FV....... set sonogram volume (default "16")
  bar_v             <string>     ..FV....... set bargraph volume (default "sono_v")
  volume2           <string>     ..FV....... set bargraph volume (default "sono_v")
showvolume AVOptions:
  c                 <string>     ..FV....... set volume color expression (default "PEAK*255+floor((1-PEAK)*255)*256+0xff000000")
  v                 <boolean>    ..FV....... display volume value (default true)
9, 0                decrease and increase volume respectively
/, *                decrease and increase volume respectively
```

Answer (score 0):

I use ffplay to loop a white noise track at 30% volume:

`ffplay ~/white_noise.m4a -loop 0 -af "volume=0.3"`

For your purposes, just remove the looping:

`ffplay <.some_file.m4a> -af "volume=0.3"`